# Why is a variable undefined when trying to analyse .bat file in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, batch-file

I am really new to MATLAB. I have to use it for a project on 3D facial image analysis. I followed procedures described at [Facial Landmarking Software](https://www.facebase.org/facial_landmarking/).

I am using Windows. I get the following error message when I run `compute_many.bat` as required in the link:

> Undefined variable "compute_many" or class "compute_many.bat".

I can see the `compute_many.bat` file generated in my folder from the code `Get_compute_many_Windows`, but I do not know why the variable is undefined.

I do not particularly understand:

> Open a terminal window, cd to either the Training or Subjects directory and execute the following command to generate the .PLY files.

How to open a terminal window? Where to type `compute_many.bat`? Does this cause the error?

Comment: In Windows you can go to the folder (either Training or Subjects as you mentioned) and type `cmd` in the address bar to open a terminal (command prompt) in the right folder. If the file `compute_many.bat` is in one of those folders, you can run it by just typing `compute_many.bat` in the command prompt. NB: I have no experience with this software.

Comment: @rinkert The terminal showed that " 'C:/Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file". Any idea why the issue here? I understand that you may not have experience with this software, but I wish to know if the issue here is a general one (if yes, how to solve) or specific to the software. Thank you.

Comment: Content of the compute_many.bat is as follows: C:/Program Files/VCG/MeshLab/meshlabserver.exe -i a1010000319.obj -o a1010000319.ply -om vc -s meancurvature.mlx    Do I need to manually quote the above content? If yes, where to place the quote marks?

Comment: Yes, place double quotes (" ") around the path of the executable, so `"C:/ ... /meshlabserver.exe"`

Comment: `.bat` files are not MATLAB scripts. Don’t try to run it from MATLAB.

Comment: Thank you all for the comments. I tried`"C:\Program Files\VCG\MeshLab\meshlabserver.exe" -i a1010000319.obj -o a1010000319.ply -om vc -s meancurvature.mlx"` but still got the following message: `"CommandLine Syntax Error: please refer to the following documentation for a complete list of the MeshLabServer parameters."`